# $ord_p(x)$ for $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory

For a prime $p$ and $x \in \mathbb{Q^{*}}$, define $ord_p(x) = ord_p(n)-ord_p(d)$, where $x = \frac{n}{d}$ with $n, d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

(a) Show that $x=\frac{p^ea}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers not divisible by $p$ and $e=ord_p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

(b) What is the intersection of all these rings $R_p$ (over all p, primes)? $R_p=\{x \in \mathbb{Q}\ |\ ord_p(x)\geq0\}$

For (a) I let $y=ord_p(n)$ and $z=ord_p(d)$ so $ap^y=n$ and $bp^z=d$ then $x=\frac{n}{d}=\frac{a}{b}p^{y-z}$.Now I am stuck.

(b) Something to do with modular arithmetic?

Comment: (a) is by and large complete. (b) write a rational number $a/b$ with $a,b$ coprime if there is some $p$ that divides $b$ the element is not in $R_p$. So  $b$ must not be divisible by any $p$ and is thus $1$.

Comment: Since $p^{y+1}$ cannot divide $n$ and $p^{z+1}$ cannot divide $n$, we get that $p$ cannot divide $a$ and $b$. But what about the power y-z =e

Comment: I am not sure what you mean to say. The $y-z=e$ is true from the definitions, and you want that term there as this is what you are supposed to show.

Comment: How do I show it belongs to z?

Comment: The orders of $n$ and $d$ are positive integers, so their difference is an integer.

Comment: Why is the element not in $R_p$ in (b)? And the answer is the integers?

Comment: How do I show the ring also contains the integers $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Yes the answer is the integers. An integer is in every $R_p$ as the p-order of an integer is non negetive. On the other question: because the $p$-order  of the element will be negative. As $a$ and $b$ are coprime $p$ does not divide $a$ so the order of $a$ is $0$ while that of $b$ is positive, whence the difference is negative. *

Comment: Thanks, so that argument shows Rp contains the integers and then I can write the intersection is the integers?

Answer (score 1):

For (a), as discussed in comments you basically did what is needed, all that is left to do is to observe that the exponent of $p$ is as claimed and that this is an integer. Recalling the definitions this is direct. 
$\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}$

For (b), I claim the intersection are the integers.

First, we show the integers are contained in each $R_p$. For an integer $z$ it is not hard to see that $\ord_p(z) \ge 0$ and we are done.

Second, we show every non-integer is not contained is some $R_p$. Let $q$ be a rational and not an integer. So $q=a/b$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $b > 1$.
Let $p$ be a prime that divides $b$. Then $p$ does not divide $a$ (as $\gcd(a,b)=1$). Now, $\ord_p(a)=0$ as $p \nmid a$ and $\ord_p(b)\ge 1$ as $p \mid p $ thus $\ord_p(q)= \ord_p(a) - \ord_p(b)<0$ and $q \notin R_p$.

Thus the intersection is exactly the integers. Only they are contained in all $R_p$